# How to simply check a previous row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm starting to belive that pandas dataframes are much less intuitive to handle than Excel, but I'm not giving up yet!

So, I'm **JUST** trying to check data in the same column but in (various) previous rows using the .shift() method. I'm using the following DF as an example since the original is too complicated to copy into here, but the principle is the same.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["one", 1],
    ["two", 2],
    ["three", 3]
], columns=["Name", "Number"]
)
```

[image]

My attempt to check the previous row with .shift() is also a simplified example, since I'm using the same approach in the original DF, just with a "float" instead of a "str" object:

```py
# If the previous row in column "Name" is not NaN, then 
# create a new column called "New Column" and set its value in the current 
# row to = 1

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row["Name"].shift().notnull: 
        df.at[index, "New Column"] = 1
```

It gives me an error:

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

Please tell me I'm missing something or using the wrong method. Shatter my believes and show me, that Excel isn't actually superior.

Comment: and what do you want in the new column if the previous row is null?

Comment: Hey Ben! That doesn't really matter, since it's just an example. My real issue is that I can't simply check the previous row with .shift().

Comment: The issue with your code is with iterrows you are accessing a single row at a time.  Therefore, you have a pd.Series, then when index it with 'Name' you are selecting a scalar value, str.   And, string doesn't have the shift method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking the previous row, you can use `np.where` along with `shift`:
Modified your df a little:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["one", 1],
    ["two", 2],
    ["three", 3],
    ["three", 3],
    [np.nan, np.nan],
    ["three", 3]
], columns=["Name", "Number"]
)

df['New column'] = np.where(~df['Name'].shift().isna(), 1, df['Name'])
df

    Name  Number New column
0    one     1.0        one
1    two     2.0          1
2  three     3.0          1
3  three     3.0          1
4    NaN     NaN          1
5  three     3.0      three
```

Comment: I think the OP wants 1 if not nan, but the idea is here :)

Comment: Ah ok :) let me change it

Comment: That doesn't really matter, since my only issue was the attribute error. But thanks! I'll give it a try :)

Comment: how would i do this in a lambda function?